# change list item to be an input text

Tags: javascript

I am working on "to do list" using Vanilla JavaScript and stuck with edit button.
This is what I have done so far.

```js
  // console.log("Hello from inside");
    const input = document.getElementById("inputText");
    const display = document.getElementById("display");
    const displayDone = document.getElementById("display-done");
    const button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    const deleteAll = document.getElementById("delete-icon");
    // const ul = document.getElementById("display");
    
    // Create and Remove list item
    function createItem() {
      let listItem = document.createElement("li");
      listItem.className = "create";
      listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
      display.appendChild(listItem);
      input.value = "";
    
      let editButton = document.createElement("button");
      editButton.innerText = "edit";
      editButton.className = "edit";
      editButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        //console.log(e.currentTarget.parentNode);
        // 1. When edit button is clicked, change list item to be an input text. <input type="text" value="my to do task"/>
        // 2. Change edit button to be something like "complete" button
        editButton.innerText = "complete";
        // 3. When complete button is clicked, change the input item to be a list item again with the updated text.
        editButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          editButton.innerText = "edit";
        });
      });
    
      let removeTask = document.createElement("input");
      removeTask.setAttribute("type", "button");
      removeTask.setAttribute("value", "X");
      removeTask.setAttribute("id", "removeButton");
      removeTask.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        listItem.parentNode.removeChild(listItem);
      });
      listItem.appendChild(editButton);
      listItem.appendChild(removeTask);
      listItem.addEventListener("dblclick", (e) => {
        displayDone.appendChild(listItem);
        listItem.style.backgroundColor = "#54e346";
        listItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        editButton.style.display = "none";
      });
    }
    
    //Make sure user fill the input
    function addAfterClick() {
      if (input.value.length > 0) {
        createItem();
      } else {
        alert("Write something mate!");
      }
    }
    
    //List item can be added with "Enter" as well
    function addWithEnter(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        addAfterClick();
      }
    }
    
    // Remove all with user approve
    function removeAll(event) {
      let answer = prompt(`Type "Delete All" If you are that sure!`);
      if (answer === "Delete All") {
        display.style.display = "none";
        location.reload();
      } else {
        alert("Try One More Time");
      }
    }
    
    //Event Listeners
    button.addEventListener("click", addAfterClick);
    input.addEventListener("keyup", addWithEnter);
    deleteAll.addEventListener("click", removeAll);
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
          <h2 class="title">to do list <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></h2>
    
          <div class="content">
            <input
              id="inputText"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Add to your list..."
              maxlength="20"
            />
            <i id="addButton" class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            <div class="remove-container">
              <i id="delete-icon" class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
              <p id="remove-text">Delete All</p>
            </div>
            <ul id="display"></ul>
          </div>
    
          <div class="completed">
            <h2 class="title-done">
              completed tasks <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
            </h2>
            <ul id="display-done"></ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

What I want to do it;

1. When edit button is clicked, change list item to be an input text.
2. Change edit button to be something like "complete" button
3. When complete button is clicked, change the input item to be a list item again with the updated text.

I have tried ChildNode.replaceWith() but did not work. Am I on the right path? and also what direction(s) I should follow. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have `editButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => ... editButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => ...));` which will add an event listener every time the button is clicked, so you'll end up with a multitude of event listeners after clicking a few times. Instead, check the value of the `innerText` property; if it's `"edit"`, change it to `"complete"`; if it's `"complete"`, change it to `"edit"`. A simple `if/else` block should work.

Comment: Thanks for that I will change it now. any idea about the editing part? I want to convert list item to input tag then I can edit.

Comment: I would think you'd want to add an input element to the list item element, rather than converting them. In that case it would just be `var input = document.createElement("input");` Add some properties to `input` (like a `value` attribute with a value that's the same as the text of the list item) and `listItem.appendChild(input)`.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to add an input field everytime you create an item:

1. at initial insertion hide the input field
2. on click on the edit button show the input and change the textNode
   after you editing

```js
 console.log("Hello from inside");
    const input = document.getElementById("inputText");
    const display = document.getElementById("display");
    const displayDone = document.getElementById("display-done");
    const button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    const deleteAll = document.getElementById("delete-icon");
    // const ul = document.getElementById("display");

// create edit input  and hide the input at first
    const editInput=document.createElement("input");
                    editInput.setAttribute("hidden",true);


// eventhandler for editInput
function editItem(e,item){
//  remove the current text node
 e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode.childNodes[0])
//    insert at the beginning of the childNodes
 e.target.parentNode.prepend( e.target.value) 
  
  e.target.setAttribute("hidden",true)
}




    // Create and Remove list item
    function createItem() {
      let listItem = document.createElement("li");
      listItem.className = "create";
      listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
     
      display.appendChild(listItem);
      input.value = "";
    
      let editButton = document.createElement("button");
      editButton.innerText = "edit";
      editButton.className = "edit";
     editInput.value=""
      editButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        // 1. When edit button is clicked, change list item to be an input text. <input type="text" value="my to do task"/>
        // 2. Change edit button to be something like "complete" button
        
//         appended edit input
         listItem.append(editInput)
        
        
        if(e.target.innerText === "edit"){
          editInput.removeAttribute("hidden",false)
       
        e.target.innerText = "complete";
          
        }else{
           
           e.target.innerText = "edit";
          
        }
//         add the event handler for the Editinput
        editInput.addEventListener("change",(e)=>editItem(e,listItem));
        editInput.value=""
        
        // 3. When complete button is clicked, change the input item to be a list item again with the updated text.
       
         
       
      });
    
      let removeTask = document.createElement("input");
      removeTask.setAttribute("type", "button");
      removeTask.setAttribute("value", "X");
      removeTask.setAttribute("id", "removeButton");
      removeTask.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        listItem.parentNode.removeChild(listItem);
      });
      listItem.appendChild(editButton);
      listItem.appendChild(removeTask);
      listItem.addEventListener("dblclick", (e) => {
        displayDone.appendChild(listItem);
        listItem.style.backgroundColor = "#54e346";
        listItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        editButton.style.display = "none";
      });
      
    }
    
    //Make sure user fill the input
    function addAfterClick() {
      if (input.value.length > 0) {
        createItem();
      } else {
        alert("Write something mate!");
      }
    }
    
    //List item can be added with "Enter" as well
    function addWithEnter(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        addAfterClick();
      }
    }
    
    // Remove all with user approve
    function removeAll(event) {
      let answer = prompt(`Type "Delete All" If you are that sure!`);
      if (answer === "Delete All") {
        display.style.display = "none";
        location.reload();
      } else {
        alert("Try One More Time");
      }
    }
    
    //Event Listeners
    button.addEventListener("click", addAfterClick);
    input.addEventListener("keyup", addWithEnter);
    deleteAll.addEventListener("click", removeAll);
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
          <h2 class="title">to do list <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></h2>
    
          <div class="content">
            <input
              id="inputText"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Add to your list..."
              maxlength="20"
            />
            <i id="addButton" class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            <div class="remove-container">
              <i id="delete-icon" class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
              <p id="remove-text">Delete All</p>
            </div>
            <ul id="display"></ul>
          </div>
    
          <div class="completed">
            <h2 class="title-done">
              completed tasks <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
            </h2>
            <ul id="display-done"></ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I like this version as well. Thanks for that! I wrapped text content with span tag and then replaceWith some input tag and It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion. you can use an input element for each item.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("inputText");
const display = document.getElementById("display");
const displayDone = document.getElementById("display-done");
const button = document.getElementById("addButton");
const deleteAll = document.getElementById("delete-icon");

const createEditBtn = () => {
  const editButton = document.createElement("button");
  editButton.innerText = "edit";
  editButton.className = "edit";
  editButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const btn = e.target;
    const input = btn.parentElement.querySelector("input");
    input.focus();
    const previousVal = input.value;
    input.addEventListener("keyup", (evt) => {
      if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
        if (input.value.trim() === "") {
          input.value = previousVal;
        }
        input.disabled = true;
        btn.disabled = false;
      }
    });
    input.addEventListener("blur", () => {
      input.disabled = true;
      btn.disabled = false;
    });
    input.disabled = false;
    btn.disabled = true;

  });

  return editButton;
}

const createRemoveBtn = () => {
  const removeBtn = document.createElement("input");
  removeBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  removeBtn.setAttribute("value", "X");
  removeBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  });
  return removeBtn;
}

const createItem = () => {
  const listItem = document.createElement("li");
  listItem.innerHTML = `<input value="${input.value}" disabled=true>`;
  display.appendChild(listItem);
  input.value = "";

  const editBtn = createEditBtn();
  listItem.appendChild(editBtn);
  listItem.appendChild(createRemoveBtn());

  listItem.addEventListener("dblclick", (e) => {
    displayDone.appendChild(listItem);
    listItem.style.backgroundColor = "#54e346";
    listItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    editBtn.style.display = "none";
  });
}

const addAfterClick = () => {
  if (input.value.length > 0) {
    createItem();
  } else {
    alert("Write something mate!");
  }
}


//List item can be added with "Enter" as well
const addWithEnter = (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    addAfterClick();
  }
}

// Remove all with user approve
const removeAll = (event) => {
  const answer = prompt(`Type "Delete All" If you are that sure!`);
  if (answer === "Delete All") {
    display.innerHTML = "";
    displayDone.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    alert("Try One More Time");
  }
}

//Event Listeners
button.addEventListener("click", addAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keyup", addWithEnter);
deleteAll.addEventListener("click", removeAll);
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <h2 class="title">to do list <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></h2>

  <div class="content">
    <input id="inputText" type="text" placeholder="Add to your list..." maxlength="20" />
    <i id="addButton" class="fas fa-plus">add Icon</i>
    <div class="remove-container">
      <i id="delete-icon" class="far fa-trash-alt">delete icon</i>
      <p id="remove-text">Delete All</p>
    </div>
    <ul id="display"></ul>
  </div>

  <div class="completed">
    <h2 class="title-done">
      completed tasks <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
    </h2>
    <ul id="display-done"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is perfect! Thank you very much!